# How do we validate a single field using python Marshmallow object serialization and deserialization framework

Tags: python-3.x, api

I made a Marshmallow Schema object like this :

```
class AlbumSchema(Schema):
    title = fields.Str()
    release_date = fields.Date()
    artist = fields.Nested(ArtistSchema())
```

and I want to validate only the field title :

```
result = AlbumSchema['title'].validate("Raspody")
print(result)

#output []

result = AlbumSchema['title'].validate(1123)
print(result)

#output ['not a valid string']
```

Can we do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To validate a single field using Marshmellow you can do something like this :

```
errors = AlbumSchema().load({"title": 1123}, partial=True)
print(result)

#output ['not a valid string']
```